# JavaScript for loop with if statement only checks the first variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a booking system using HTML and JavaScript. This is a simplified version of my code which should check if the selected time matches any variables from the bookings array.

The loop is working (it works when I replace the if statements with console.log(bookings[i]);).

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <input type="time" name="time" id="time">
  <button id="submit" class="button">Submit</button>
  <script>
    var bookings = ["10:00", "10:15", "10:30"];

    function addBooking() {
      for (i = 0; i < bookings.length; i++) {
        if (bookings[i] == document.getElementById("time").value) {
          alert("Time unavailable.");
        } else {
          alert("Booking succesful.");
        }
        break;
      }
    }
    document.getElementById("submit").addEventListener("click", addBooking);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When the form is submitted, the function only checks the first variable (if I type in 10:00 it alerts that time is unavailable but if I type 10:15 or 10:30 it alerts "Booking successful") when it should alert "Time unavailable" if the input matches any variables from the bookings array.
EDIT: removing break does NOT solve the problem.

Comment: try moving the break statement to inside if block

Comment: You're breaking after first iteration itself

Comment: `break` keyword is culprit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you always `break` after the first check! so you're only comparing the first value with the input, also you don't have to explicitly loop over the values, in your case you can just do it with an if statement, like this

```
if (bookings.indexOf(document.getElementById("time").value) === -1) {
    alert("Booking succesful.");
} else {
    alert("Time unavailable.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

- You're alerting on **every** loop iteration, and
- You're stopping (with `break`) after the first iteration

Instead, have a flag, and stop only when you've seen that the time is unavailable:

```
function addBooking() {
    var available = true;
    for (i = 0; available && i < bookings.length; i++) {
        if (bookings[i] == document.getElementById("time").value) {
            avalable = false;
        }
    }
    if (available) {
        alert("Booking succesful.");
    }
    else {
        alert("Time unavailable.");
    }
}
```

In that example I've added `available &&` to the loop condition. You could choose to use `break` instead:

```
function addBooking() {
    var available = true;
    for (i = 0; i < bookings.length; i++) {
        if (bookings[i] == document.getElementById("time").value) {
            available = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (available) {
        alert("Booking succesful.");
    }
    else {
        alert("Time unavailable.");
    }
}
```

You can also use `includes` to find out if an array includes a value:

```
function addBooking() {
    if (bookings.includes(document.getElementById("time").value)) {
        alert("Time unavailable.");
    }
    else {
        alert("Booking succesful.");
    }
}
```

---

In all of the above, I'd probably get the `value` from the input into a variable **once**, and then reuse the variable:

```
function addBooking() {
    var desiredTime = document.getElementById("time").value;
    if (bookings.includes(desiredTime)) {
        alert("Time unavailable.");
    }
    else {
        alert("Booking succesful.");
    }
}
```